# How can I get the value of a gurobi variable?

Tags: python, gurobi

How can I access only to the value of the variable?

Example:

When I print forces[0,1], I obtain: gurobi.Var forces[0,1] (value -0.6)

How can access only to the value of the variable: -0.6?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are using python?

If `forces[0,1]` is a Gurobi variable-object, and a value is available, you can access the value (more precise: *current solution*) with:

```
forces[0,1].X
```

This is of course explained in the [docs](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/refman/attributes.html). Look for *variable attributes*! ([.X](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/refman/x.html#attr:X))

(Above links are for Gurobi's Python-API; look up the corresponding docs for other APIs if needed)